# Allegro para dev c++ 6.3 pls

Tags: c++, dev-c++, interfaz-gráfica, interfaz, allegro

Gracias por escogerme, necesito de tu ayuda por favor :(, ¿Cómo puedo instalar allegro para el entorno de desarrollo integrado dev_c++ en la versión 6.3 del IDE?
No se que versión de allegro es compatible ni como instalarlo, lo eh instalado en codeblocks pero no se que versión instalarle a dev c++ ni como configurarlo por favor si saben por aqui por favor.
GRACIAS :).

Answer (score 0):

como estas, un gusto contribuir:

1. Descomprime el archivo en cualquier directorio y verás que aparece el fichero allegro-4.2.0-1mol.DevPak, le das doble click y se te presenta una pantalla como la siguiente:
2. Se presenta el clásico ReadMe, das click nuevamente en Next:
3. Ahora viene el acuerdo de licencia, das click ahora en Install y empezará el proceso de instalación
4. Una vez terminada la instalación se presentan la siguiente pantalla indicandonos que le proceso ha sido exitoso. Click en Finish y terminamos esta parte.

Prueba de la librería

1. Abre el compilador, vas a Archivo -> Nuevo -> Proyecto y en la pestaña Multimedia seleccionas Allegro application (static) y das click en Aceptar:
2. Selecciona en donde quieres guardar el archivo del proyecto y se te presentará a continuación un código de ejemplo, el cual simplemente muestra como inicializar la librería:
3. Presiona CTRL+S para guardar el archivo fuente mostrado. Luego presiona CTRL+F9 para compilar el programa, se presentará un cuadro indicandonos que la compilación ha sido exitosa, damos click en Cerrar.
4. Por último presiona CTRL+F10 para ejecutar el programa, verás una pantalla negra, presiona ESC para salir.

Este es compatible : http://www.mediafire.com/file/ca51pfdip54bgpx/Allegro.rar/file

Comment: Alejando gracias por tu respuesta, no me quiere instalar se queda en 1% desde anoche :(